# putting breakpoints in gdb at every assignment of a variable

Tags: gdb

I am trying to make a script for putting breakpoint at every assignment of a variable in gdb. The directory in which to look for the code is to be specified in the script command. 
For eg: "b minSize dir1 dir2" will put a breakpoint in all assignments of minSize in cpp code in directories dir1 and dir2.
Does anyone have an idea if this can be done in gdb or through unix command line which calls gdb? Please tell me how should I start working on this?

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok to stop after the variable was changed instead of before, then you don't actually need to add a breakpoint for every assignment. You can use gdb [watch](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) command instead. It will stop whenever the value of an expression (which can be just the variable value) changes. In fact, this has the advantage that even if the variable is changed through other means (a reference or a pointer) gdb will still stop after the change. This would be very difficult to do with your approach.

As an example, consider the code below

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Starting the program" << std::endl;

  int a = 5;
  int &b = a;

  a = 3;

  std::cout << "Something else" << std::endl;

  b = 9;
  std::cout << "Value of a changed" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "The program ended" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If you run this program in gdb and do `watch a`, then gdb will stop in the line with `int a = 5` (the value of `a` will already be 5). After continuing execution gdb will stop in the line after `a = 3;`. Continuing execution again gdb will stop in the line after `b = 9;`, since `b` is a reference to `a` and changing it will change `a`.

If you need to stop **before** the value is changed, then you can still use the `watch` command and use [reverse debugging](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html) to "go back in time" to before the value is changed (I haven't tried this).